# Error using WHILE LOOP in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to run a SQL query in MySQL (MariaDB 5.5.39)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END;
```

But when I run that query I get the following error(s)

```
MariaDB [elis27rel]> source /home/vagrant/test.sql;
--------------
CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5
--------------

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1 in file: '/home/vagrant/test.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
'' at line 3
--------------
WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    SET v1 = v1 - 1
--------------

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 5 in file: '/home/vagrant/test.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
'WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    SET v1 = v1 - 1' at line 1
--------------
END WHILE
--------------

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 7 in file: '/home/vagrant/test.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
'END WHILE' at line 1
--------------
END
--------------

ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 8 in file: '/home/vagrant/test.sql': You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near
'END' at line 1
```

I don't know what the issues with my code are. I copied and pasted that code from the mysql website http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/while.html and was hoping to use that script to get my feet wet. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That sample code has semicolons at the end of various lines.  You will want a `delimiter` statement before (and after) the stored procedure, something like `delimiter $$ . . . <stored procedure> . . . delimiter ;`.

Comment: In the SQL file? or as separate commands in mysql? Could you show me an example using my query?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE dowhile()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 5;

  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
    SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END;

DELIMITER ;
```

The delimiter tells MySQL not to end the statement at the semi-colon -- which would be a problem because the stored procedure definition isn't finished at the first semicolon.