# While-loop end error mysql

Tags: mysql, while-loop, dbeaver

I am using DBeaver and here is the code of mysql procedure:

```
drop procedure if exists transfertweets;
create procedure transfertweets()
BEGIN
set @id_lower = 13505;
set @id_end = 14118801;
set @batch = 6;
set @id_upper = 13505;
while @id_lower < @id_end DO
end while;
END
```

Problem is that whenever I add this while loop it gives me error given in image. If I remove this while loop it runs perfectly. It's bugging me now.Thanks in advance [image]

Comment: consider enclosing your condition within '()' brackets...

Comment: Already did, not worked. By the way I am using mysql 5.1.39.

Comment: might be delimiter problem try with this thread....http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25514175/error-using-while-loop-in-mysql-query

Comment: I've tried it too. Still error with while loop.

Comment: Your while loop triggers an infinite loop. You have no condition to increment `@id_lower` within your loop. Here's the [while syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/while.html) you should be following